# Why doesnt this print X? Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, bios

Why doesnt this program print X? Could someone explain step by step what is happening to make it print a spade as output.

```
mov ah, 0x0e ; Set higher bit of ax to 0e (probably the instruction opcode)
mov al, the_secret ; Set lower bit of ax to bytes of H
int 0x10

the_secret:
    db 'X'

jmp $ ;Jump to the current address forever

; Padding

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: I think you want `[the_secret]` (note the brackets). You should also set the _DS_ segment register to what you expect. You don't have an `ORG` directive and we don't see your commands to build the bootloader so I can't say for certain what value you should put in _DS_. If you are using nasm with `-f bin` then your ORG will default to 0x0000. In that case you should move 0x07c0 to _DS_ with something like `mov ax, 0x07c0` `mov ds, ax` as the first part of your bootloader.

Comment: What I meant by `[the_secret]` was that the instruction should have looked like `mov al, [the_secret]` since you wanted to get the byte at memory address `the_secret` and put it in _AL_ rather than put the memory address in _AL_

Comment: And if you had an `ORG 0x7c00` in your code but just didn't show it in your question then you want to put the value `0` into _DS_.

Comment: One other issue. You should place `jmp $` before your data and after `int 0x10` otherwise the CPU will try to execute `the_secret` as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... to make it print a ***spade*** as output.

... now I can't really help you there, as I don't know the exact Hex->ASCII Value for a **♠️** character... although, I can help you understand the simple steps in how to print a *standard* (keystroke) ASCII character.

Here's the full ***NASM*** example of how to go about printing character(s) to the monitor display; I will break it down into **video display specific** chunks to help you better understand the process (please take care to note that I've used only ***REAL MODE*** assembly instructions (16 Bit) within the example):

```
[bits   16]                                             ; Declare CPU Instructions as [REAL_MODE]
[org    0x0000]                                         ; Organize Memory to Start @ [0x0000]
                                                        ; We'll Manually setup Memory Organization Later...


jmp _glEntry                                            ; Relocate to Function:



;========================================================
; This Function Prints an Entire Character Stream until
; NULL Terminated Hex Character (0x00) is Detected...
;========================================================
output16_char_array:                                    ; Legacy BIOS Output CHAR_STREAM Function
    ;push   ax                                          ; Store [AX] Register to [STACK_SPACE]
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ah, 0x0E                                        ; Assign [0x0E] to [AX] : (Legacy BIOS Function Code for BIOS Display)
                                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    .output16_char_array_loop:
        lodsb                                           ; Collect Single Byte from [DS:SI] and increment SI by 1 : ([AL] = [DS:SI]; inc [SI])
        or  al, al                                      ; Check Whether [AL] is [0x00]
        jz  .output16_char_array_done                   ; [AL] == [0x00] Proceed to Function:
        int 0x10                                        ; [AL] != [0x00] Continue to Display Hex->ASCII [CHAR]
        jmp .output16_char_array_loop                   ; Relocate [CS] to create an Infinite Loop...
    
    .output16_char_array_done:
        ;pop    ax                                      ; Restore [AX] Register from [STACK_SPACE]
        ret                                             ; Return to Calling [CS] Memory Position...



;========================================================
; For Simplicity I've created a Single Character Output
; Method, but in the form of a MACRO
;
; There is really no difference in the method if Output
; other than that this method only prints a single
; Character and doesn't require a NULL Terminated Hex
; Character (0x00) for EndOf(..) CHAR_STREAM...
;========================================================
%macro  output16_char_byte  1                           ; Define Macro with a single input method...
    ;push   ax                                          ; Store [AX] Register to [STACK_SPACE]
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ah, 0x0E                                        ; Assign [0x0E] to [AH] : (Legacy BIOS Function Code for BIOS Display)
    mov al, %1                                          ; Assign [MACRO_INPUT] to [AL] : (Refer to ['%macro output16_char_byte <..>'])
    int 0x10                                            ; Legacy BIOS Interrupt for Teletype Output
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    ;pop    ax                                          ; Restore [AX] Register from [STACK_SPACE]
%endmacro                                               ; End of ['output16_char_byte'] Macro


WELCOME_MSG db  "Hello, World!",    0x0D,   0x0A,   0x00



;========================================================
; This Function is the Entry Point for the Global Master
; Boot Record
;========================================================
_glEntry:
    cli                                                 ; Disable CPU Interrupts
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ax, 0x07E0                                      ; Assign [0x07E0] to [AX] : (0x07E0)
    mov ss, ax                                          ; Assign [AX] to [SS] : ([AX]*[0x0010]) : (0x7E00)
    mov sp, 0x1000                                      ; Assign [0x1000] to [SP] : (0x1000) ([0x07E0]:[0x1000])
    sti                                                 ; Enable CPU Interrupts
                                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ax, 0x07C0                                      ; Assign [0x07C0] to [AX] : (0x07C0)
    mov ds, ax                                          ; Assign [AX] to [DS] : ([AX]*[0x0010]) : (0x7C00)
                                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    mov si, WELCOME_MSG                                 ; Assign [WELCOME_MSG] to [SI] : (0x[....])
    call    output16_char_array                         ; Call our Output [CHAR_STREAM] Function
    
    mov si, WELCOME_MSG                                 ; Assign [WELCOME_MSG] to [SI] : (0x[....])
    output16_char_byte  BYTE    [ds:si+0x0008]          ; Assign (BYTE) [DS:SI+0x0008] to Macro Input Method...
                                                        ; we should have the (9th - 1) letter from [WELCOME_MSG] 'o'
    
                                                        ; Continue Code Execution on Return:
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    int 0x16                                            ; Call BIOS Await Keystroke Interrupt
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    int 0x19                                            ; Call BIOS Reboot Interrupt
                                                        ; Continue Code Execution if interrupts fail...
    cli                                                 ; Disable CPU Interrupts
    hlt                                                 ; Halt CPU Execution:



times   510 - ( $ - $$ )    db  0x00                    ; Pad [BOOTSECTOR] with [0x00] up to 510 Bytes...
dw  0xAA55                                              ; Assign [MAGIC_MBR] Value...
```

Alright that is the entirety of how one would go about printing characters to the monitor/display... [image: here's photo evidence of the true output:]

Most common/efficient method of printing/displaying character(s) to the display:

```
;========================================================
; This Function Prints an Entire Character Stream until
; NULL Terminated Hex Character (0x00) is Detected...
;========================================================
output16_char_array:                                    ; Legacy BIOS Output CHAR_STREAM Function
    ;push   ax                                          ; Store [AX] Register to [STACK_SPACE]
    xor ax, ax                                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ah, 0x0E                                        ; Assign [0x0E] to [AX] : (Legacy BIOS Function Code for BIOS Display)
                                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    .output16_char_array_loop:
        lodsb                                           ; Collect Single Byte from [DS:SI] and increment SI by 1 : ([AL] = [DS:SI]; inc [SI])
        or  al, al                                      ; Check Whether [AL] is [0x00]
        jz  .output16_char_array_done                   ; [AL] == [0x00] Proceed to Function:
        int 0x10                                        ; [AL] != [0x00] Continue to Display Hex->ASCII [CHAR]
        jmp .output16_char_array_loop                   ; Relocate [CS] to create an Infinite Loop...

    .output16_char_array_done:
        ;pop    ax                                      ; Restore [AX] Register from [STACK_SPACE]
        ret                                             ; Return to Calling [CS] Memory Position...
```

I would like to note that I've commented `push   ax` & `pop    ax` as these instructions are not required within this simple example. Although, (off topic) these instructions just preform a memory stack store (`push`) and/or restore (`pop`) to the `AX` register.

`mov ah, 0x0E` this is pretty straight forward... it assigns the value `0x0E` to `AH` this is the [Teletype Output Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) for `int 0x10`.

`lodsb` this is a more efficient way of preforming such:

```
mov    al,    BYTE    [SI]           ; Assign Single [BYTE] from [SI] to [AL]
inc    si                            ; Increment [SI] by 1 equivalent to [SI]++
```

`or  al, al` checks whether `[AL]` is equal to `0x00`. This is the `NULL` terminating character of a character stream.

`jz  .output16_char_array_done` if `[AL]` is equal to `0x00` then execute code at `.output16_char_array_done`... if `[AL]` is **not** equal to `0x00` continue to execute the code...

`jmp .output16_char_array_loop` a simple way to *loop* or *iterate* a certain function/handle without using the `loop` instruction (`loop` requires more hardware resources to execute, so tend to avoid this instruction unless it's more efficient in *your* specific circumstance(s)).

`ret` a simple instruction to return to previous (calling) memory address.

`int 0x10` this is the [BIOS Interrupt Handle for Video Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H)